# showBluetoothAccessoryPicker doesn't display on screen

Tags: swift, bluetooth

my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.addSubview(connectBtn)
    connectBtn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    connectBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    connectBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    connectBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    connectBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showAccessoryPicker), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func showAccessoryPicker() {
    EAAccessoryManager.shared().showBluetoothAccessoryPicker(withNameFilter: nil, completion: nil)
}
```

debug console

```
2020-07-21 15:26:40.674865+0800 StarPrnt[22299:6727201] A constraint factory method was 
passed a nil layout anchor.  This is not allowed, and may cause confusing exceptions. Break 
on BOOL _NSLayoutConstraintToNilAnchor(void) to debug.  This will be logged only once.  This 
may break in the future.
```

[mPOP Printer](http://www.starasia.com/productdetail.asp?lang=EN) I used official SDK to connect is work fine